# How to update data and view of my customized cell subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a customized view to add on my cell containView.
But when I update my data, and I use reloadData to reload tableview.
The view doesn't change like nothing happening.
I want to add one item "A6" to my view.
What's wrong with me.
Have any idea to refresh the view? Thanks.

My view like following image.
The items update accroding to the infos array.

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var alreadyLoadCell: Bool = false

    var initInfos = [Info(name: A1, color: UIColor.A1), Info(name: A2, color: UIColor.A2), Info(name: A3, color: UIColor.A3), Info(name: A4, color: UIColor.A4), Info(name: A5, color: UIColor.A5)]

    var updateInfos = [Info(name: A1, color: UIColor.A1), Info(name: A2, color: UIColor.A2), Info(name: A3, color: UIColor.A3), Info(name: A4, color: UIColor.A4), Info(name: A5, color: UIColor.A5), Info(name: A6, color: UIColor.A6)]         


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

            if alreadyLoadCell == false {
                customCell.initCell(infos: initInfos)
                alreadyLoadCell = true
            }else{
                //TODO: reloadData to update cell
                customCell.updateCell(infos: updateInfos)
            }

            return customCell

        }

       return UITableViewCell()            
    }

}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var testItemView: UIView?

    func initCell(infos: [Info]) {

        self.testItemView = createItemView(infos: infos)

        self.contentView.addSubview(testItemView!)

        testItemView?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.left.equalTo(13)
            make.top.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(-13)
            make.height.equalTo(195)
            make.bottom.equalTo(-10)
        }

   }

   func updateCell(infos: [Info]) {

       self.testContainView = createItemView(infos: infos)
       //How to update successful?

   }


    func createItemView(infos: [Info]) -> UIView {

        let contentView = UIView()
        var serialNumber = 0
        var previousView: TitleView?

        for info in infos {

            let view = TitleView(assets: info, color: info.color)
            contentView.addSubview(view)
            switch serialNumber {
            case 0: //A1
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.left.equalTo(15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135)
                    make.top.equalToSuperview()
                }
                previousView = view
            case 1: //A2
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135)
                    make.top.equalToSuperview()
                }
                previousView = view
            case 2: //A3
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.left.equalTo(15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135)                
                    make.top.equalTo((previousView?.snp.bottom)!).offset(5)
                }
                previousView = view
            case 3: //A4
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135)
                    make.centerY.equalTo((previousView?.snp.centerY)!)
                }
                previousView = view
            case 4: //A5
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.left.equalTo(15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135) 
                    make.top.equalTo((previousView?.snp.bottom)!).offset(5)
                }
                previousView = view
            case 5: //A6
                view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
                    make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-15)
                    make.width.equalTo(135)
                    make.centerY.equalTo((previousView?.snp.centerY)!)
                }
                previousView = view
            default:
                break
            }

            serialNumber += 1
        }

        return contentView
    }

}
```

Comment: share your info class!!

Comment: Why are you trying to add more views?  Shouldn't you be adding more cells?

Comment: @Pushp My class Info just init function.

Comment: @Paulw11 because I don't know how to update, have any good idea to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, before updating cell, you should remove from superview early initiated `testItemView`, because at `updateCells` method you are create new instance of `testItemView` and add for new created view constraints again.

---

I think this code should work for you, replace you updateCell method:

```
func updateCell(infos: [Info]) {
   testContainView.removeFromSuperView
   testContainView = createItemView(infos: infos)

   contentView.addSubview(testItemView!)

   testItemView?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(13)
        make.top.equalTo(10)
        make.right.equalTo(-13)
        make.height.equalTo(195)
        make.bottom.equalTo(-10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your advice.

Answer (score 1):

It's **not OK** to recreate elements inside of reusable cell. That would affect the performance of the App itself. Imagine having **1000** cells with that layout and every time you scroll it recreates everything from the scratch.

You use the same function `createItemView` for update and init, which is not necessary.

Instead, create custom **xib** layout with all your elements and with your A6 element that is initially hidden. Connect all the elements from xib to your custom cell class. In that way you'll always have all the elements in the place, and you just need to update the values for infos.

So, inside of `cellForRowAt` function instead of calling init or update, just update the data like:

```
customCell.someLabel.text = "example text"
```

or

```
    if infos.count == 6 {
    
        // this could mean that you have A6 in your array
    
        customCell.A6.isHidden = false
        customCell.A6. // change A6 element as you wish
    
    } else {
     
        customCell.A6.isHidden = true

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. And I have a question. If I just have two items A1 and A2, how to update it's height?

Comment: In xib file, you add an item and then you set its constraints. You can always connect those constraints with your code and later update its constant. So, for example if you wanna change the height of A1, you connect its height constraint with your code and then in view controller you access that constraint like: customCell.A1HeightConstraint.constant = 44

Comment: @JimmyLee if my answer helped you solve your problem, would you mind checking it as a right answer. Thank you!